# File Association - How to insert file name as a command line argument

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer, file-association

I know how to associate certain file extensions in a deployment project but when one of those files is opened I want to pass the file name to my application to proceed with the correct action.

I can specify what to send as a command line argument in the File Types tab of my deployment project as seen in Img 1.

[image: Img 1]

How can i get the actual file name of the file that was opened to be used as the value of Arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"%1"` in place of `"%FileName"`. Make sure you surround it in double-quotes, so that you properly get filenames with spaces in the name or path. If your app can accept more than one filename, or need more than one parameter, treat them the same way, using `"%2"` and so forth. Make sure each one is separated from the others by a space, and surround them with double-quote characters.

Comment: If I may ask, ive tried what you've said and it works 100% :D  I was just wondering why %0 doesn't work instead because I thought the filename/path would be at argv[0]?

Comment: @user968243: `argv[0]` is the fully-qualified path and name of the current executable, not the first command line argument. IOW, (on Windows) if you run `myapp.exe` from the `C:\Temp` folder, `argv[0]` contains `C:\Temp\myapp.exe`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Im aware of what argv[0] is; I would've thought that %0 would represent the filename and path of the associated file, and thus using %0 would access argv[0] of the associated file. And I would've thought that placing %0 in the argument box would send argv[0] to the main exe.